# ¿Es posible limitar las filas que se importan desde SQL server a Power BI?

Tags: sql-server, excel, powerbi

Uno de los campos que se importan es un campo fecha y tiene más de 5 millones de registros, necesito filtrarlos antes de importarlos a Power BI, no tengo acceso a la BD. ¿existe alguna forma en la importación de datos de SSAS que permita aplicar algún filtro para limitar las filas a importar en PBI?

Answer (score 1):

Primera opción: Para poder buscar por rango de fechas contra una columna de fechas en el Advanced Editor crea 2 parámetros de tipo "any"y  entra una fórmula parecida a:

```
= Table.SelectRows(#"Reordered Columns", each [KeyDateTime] >= DateTimeZone.From(StartDate) and [KeyDateTime] <= DateTimeZone.From(EndDate))
```

y para una columna numérica en la base de datos que pueda contener nulos, crea un parámetro tipo "text"y entra la fórmula

```
= Table.SelectRows(#"Filtered Rows2", each (Text.From([InspMethod]) = InspMethod) or (InspMethod = "ALL") or (([InspMethod] = null) and (InspMethod = "BLANK")))
```

De esa manera puede entrar "ALL" para traer todos los registros. EL usuario puede entrar "BLANK" para traer filas o registros con nulos, o puede traer registros con el valor que el introduzca.

Otra opción es ir al Power Query Editor haz click en el ícono Table.
Haz click en "Keep Top Row column" y entra el número de regitros que quieres se returnen.

Answer (score 1):

Si estás usando SSAS 2017+ o AAS (compatibilidad 1400) podrás entrar a las propiedades de la tabla que es semejante al editor de consultas de Power Bi. Donde podrás filtrar las tablas como en excel seleccionando las columnas y eligiendo bajo que condiciones hacerlo.

Sino la otra posibilidad que funciona en todos los casos sería no conectar la tabla directamente con el conector SQL seleccionada por wizard sino elegir la opción de realizarle una consulta a la BD. Ahi podrías hacerlo por T-SQL: "SELECT * FROM WHERE columna1 > ...."

Espero que te sirva.